# Could rice or pasta be cooked without hot water?

Tags: pasta, rice, temperature, water

I moved in a brand new house. I have no stove, microwaves or hot water for a week or two.

I'm vegetarian and I've already prepared fresh veggies wrap, salad, hummus, sandwichs, .. but I'm wondering if you could cook any kind of pasta or rice without hot water.

A long time ago I read [pasta could be softened in cold water](http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/05/how-to-cook-pasta-salt-water-boiling-tips-the-food-lab.html) before boiling it to cook it quicker.

Comment: What about something like a coffee pot?  Instead of putting coffee in the filter, just let it heat your water and then cook something like couscous which just needs to stand in hot water?  Or you could use an electric kettle or hot pot.  Alternatively a rice cooker would work for rice.

Comment: I don't have a coffee pot or a rice cooker :( I have a moka pot. I have no hot water at all.

Comment: If it's going to be a week or two you could just buy an electric kettle. There are some really cheap ones.

Comment: A small microwave is pretty cheap, too—somewhere around $50.

Comment: Why don't you cook it in the oven?

Comment: @simonmiller I suspect that the OP doesn't have an oven either if they don't have a stove.

Comment: @simonmiller : depending on the country, the norm might be that you take your appliances when you sell the house, including the stove/fridge/etc.  In the U.S., it's typical that the large kitchen appliances transfer with the house, but not so much in Europe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wetted starch is not the same thing as cooked starch. If you want to see the difference in a simple experiment, make two starch slurries, boil one into a pudding, and leave the other one cold. Starch only gelates at high temperatures (I think it starts around 70°C, but needs even more to complete the process).

When you have a grain of rice, you have the problem that the starch is very closely packed together, and water can't penetrate into the center of the grain too well - the outside layers soak all the water they come in contact with, and so water only seeps into the center of the rice after the outer part has been hydrated. It is similar for pasta. In the worst case, when you cook rice, the time needed for cooking will be enough to heat the whole grain to the gelating temperature, but not enough for the water to hydrate the innermost part of the corn. This is fine if you want hardish-cooked rice, but if you want soft, mushy rice, you should presoak it so the inside is already hydrated when you start cooking it. I suppose you can do the same with pasta. This is the reason why some sources will advice you to presoak.

But, as I said, this is not the same as cooking. Yes, the rice or pasta will get soft, so you won't break your teeth if you try to eat it. But it will still be raw starch. I don't know if it is unhealthy to eat raw starch (my mother certainly told me so, but it could have been a myth; I asked [a question about that](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/can-we-digest-raw-starch) and got no conclusive answers). But it will probably taste unpleasant, similar to raw potatoes or raw flour. I would try to get other sources of food for this time period. Or, as @justkt's comment suggests, it is easy to get an electric kettle in a brand new house before the kitchen is installed. You can use it to pour cooking water over "instant" versions of pasta and rice. These have been pregelated and then dehydrated, so don't need a prologned cooking. They are usually available as instant hot soup or rice meals in sachets and cardboard boxes, I haven't seen them as pure ingredients.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right about the flour flavour. 
I'll try it anyways with a little portion of pasta to see how it grows and taste.

Comment: I try it and the rice is still tough after 4 hours. The pasta was a paste after a few minutes. The pasta was pretty disgusting :S

Comment: The rice will need much longer, normally presoaking for rice is overnight (assuming you plan to cook it afterwards). But I doubt that it will taste much better than the pasta.

Answer (score 5):

[Ramen, or instant, noodles are usually precooked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_noodles), so you ought to be able to get away with just a cold water soak.  [ramen "no cook"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ramen+%22no+cook%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) turns up many recipes, but I'm not finding [how long a soak is needed for rehydration with cold water](http://www.whiteblaze.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-79760.html?s=3f0f9b4ac553ff266b35db368d39475e).

Comment: +1 for dry instant ramen. I will sometimes crumble up a pack before opening, open the pack and add a little bit of the seasoning, shake the pack carefully to distribute the seasoning, and chomp down on that. In a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

You can make rice in a crock pot. There are 2 methods that I know of, one of which I use all the time.

1. (this is the one I haven't used, but have heard of it from reliable sources) An hour before serving your meal, fill a crock pot liner with the amount of water/salt/rice that you would normally use. Put it at the top of the pot, using the lid to keep it there (meaning to put both sides of the top of the bag over the lid of the pot and put the cover over the edges). Fluff with a fork before eating.
2. I take a pyrex or any other oven safe bowl that's big enough to hold the amount of cooked rice that I want, put the rice, water, and whatever else I want into the bowl, and put it in the crockpot at the beginning of the cook time for whatever dish I'm making. I put it to the side of the main dish that is already cooking in there. It comes out perfect every time.

This is, of course, assuming you have access to a slow cooker (which would probably be a good idea if you don't have access to hot water or a stove).

Comment: I have no crock pot or rice cooker. No hot water at all at home. I am in a hot weather place, so is not a big problem for having a shower ;)

Comment: Hmmm If you are in a place with hot weather, perhaps you can utilize the sun to boil water. I've seen sun ovens done before. I dont see why you can't utilize the same heat trapping concept to boil water.

Comment: @Jay you can, indeed its how some solar-thermal power plants work. Of course, this would be much more work than a $15 electric kettle, but could be more fun.

Answer (score 0):

Camp stove.  Sterno cans at sporting goods store--cheap.  Or outside grill--but it will take a while.

Remember you only need to bring it to boil or very hot, then let it sit for a while.

Comment: Hi Steve. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Contrary to a lot of the discussion on this page, the original question is about not using hot water (from any source.) I'm with you, I'd rather _find_ a way to make hot water than attempt to eat lukewarm, uncooked rice. But it's not the question at hand.

Comment: It is true. A cup of near boiling water placed into a container, add some pasta, cover it and 20 minutes or so, it will be cooked. I think this is the best answer to the logical follow-up to this question, since pasta cannot be cooked without heat or a chemical reaction of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind.  First, 'instant' rice or noodles are likely precooked or partially so, or otherwise processed so that cooking isn't required to be digestible (the hot water serving to rehydrate and warm the food instead).  It is likely that a longer soak in cold water would be able to rehydrate them, and they would likely be much more digestible than attempting the same with an uncooked variety - the problems with witch are mentioned in rumtscho's answer.  It might be helpful to set the soaking rice or noodles in the sun, the warmth will help the process along even if it never boils, much like sun tea.

The second idea might be technically correct but is less helpful, and I really *do not* recommend taking it seriously unless you can find a *really* reputable source/recipe/expert - but it might be possible to breakdown the starches of the raw foods in a way that makes it edible, by fermenting it.  This is not totally unknown - dhosa or idli are sometimes made from fermented rice dough, and fermented flour (which raw pasta is made from) pretty much gets you to a sourdough situation.  However, both of these require further cooking (either baking or pan-frying), and so are probably not safe to consume without that further step.  Even such recipes as Taipei fermented rice-wine soup or lacto-fermented rice are boiled at some point before consumption. So while that further cooking doesn't have to require "hot water" specifically, thus fulfilling the question's requirements, hot water is usually trivial to produce if you have any other method of cooking.  I suppose you might be able to sun-bake the results if you have some dark stone out in the sunlight that gets hot enough (in the spirit of cooking eggs on a sidewalk), or sun-dried then toasted over open flames (as in, say, a candle).  But, again, I don't recommend it unless you've got a really good source for how to do so *safely*.

Answer (score -2):

Rice is made to be hot. The chemical reaction happens through enough energy to allow the water in, otherwise, you get stale rice.

Comment: Hi MJO. Welcome to Seasoned Advice. There are some issues with your answer that are causing it to be downvoted. The first one that I see is that you mention a chemical reaction but do not mention what reaction you are speaking of. Since you do not include any reference to a source document it's hard to verify this claim. "Rice is made to be hot" is also kind of a weird claim. Rice is grown to live and procreate like anything else. We value precise wording and science above general advice.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald I don't think the idea here is that rice evolved or was created to be hot; it's just that in the context of cooking rice is meant to be cooked hot. It's circular, so it's certainly not a useful answer, but your response is a bit odd.

Comment: @Jefromi I thought my closing sentence would be enough to explain my pedanticism. Guess not.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald In that case, I completely disagree: we value useful answers above pedantry. You can always edit to address pedantry if you really have to, but if the answer's useful, it's useful, nitpicking or not.

Comment: I think this answer is referring to lectin in the rice and other agglutinins that have indeed been increased in modern rice varieties https://www.amymyersmd.com/2017/06/the-problem-with-grains-and-legumes/  
Milkjuice's Own answer is perhaps worded incompletely or poorly but there is verifiable substance to it - modern rice varieties have had their natural antibacterial and anti-fungal properties engineered to be stronger and rely for edibility and safety on full high heat cooking.

Comment: Consider solar cooking, the sun can cook far more easily than most people think. Avoid the standard pizza box crap, build a solar funnel, look it up.